# Unable to retrieve emails based on subject line using Java Mail API

Tags: java

```
public class testemail {
java.lang.Comparable c[];
Properties properties = null;
private Session session = null;
private Store store = null;
private Folder inbox = null;
private String userName = "xxx@gmail.com";  //
private String password = "xxx";
public testemail() {

}

public void readMails() throws Exception {
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
    session = Session.getInstance(properties,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    });


        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect();
        inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        //Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
        Message messages[]=inbox.getMessages();
    //  System.out.println("Number of mails = " + messages.length);




        for ( Message message : messages ) {
            System.out.println("Subject: "+ message.getSubject());
            if(message.getSubject().toString()=="Suppliers that match your search: suto in future mode")
            {
            Address[] from = message.getFrom();
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
            //System.out.println("From : " + from[0]);
            //System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            //System.out.println("Content :");

            Object content = message.getContent();
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
            //procesMultiPart(multiPart);

            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
        }
        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();


}
```

### Output:

```
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: Test 13 mar 2012 Automotive
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: suto in future mode
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: ttt
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search:
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: 123
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: Search1
   not found
   Subject: Suppliers that match your search: Jan 28 US by vani
   not found
   Subject: Sign-in attempt prevented
   not found
   Subject: Stay more organised with Gmail's inbox
   not found
```

I am trying to filter out email with the subject line :"Suppliers that match your search: suto in future mode"
the above program is unable to locate it even thought the email is available. kIndly help :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `==` to `.equals()` method in `if(message.getSubject().toString()=="Suppliers that match your search: suto in future mode")`

FYI look for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), shortly it's about this: 
`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object) while `.equals()` compares for value equality (whether they are logically "equal") and that's your case.
So, if you want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed while skimming over your code that you wrote

```
if(message.getSubject().toString()=="Suppliers that match your search: suto in future mode")
```

When programming in Java, comparing strings should be done with the ".equals()" method rather than "==".